# How do I cancel a server request via javascript? (not an AJAX)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button cancel a document request from the server while it is loading, I've tried window.stop() on Chrome but it does not prevent the page from reloading. I've also tried those lines but they get me back a blank page, which is not what I want, I need just to stop the request, as if pressing the Esc key.

```
document.write('<script type="text/undefined">'); or
document.write('<!--');
```

When I click the button and immediately press the Esc key I get the result wanted

edit: coming back to this question after some time, what I meant was actually:

"How do I prevent a request from **loading** the response sent by the server in **user** side"

Comment: `cancel a document request from the server while it is loading`  `I've set the img src to change onClick` stuff don't add up, is it an image or a document in an iframe or what exactly ?

Comment: `window.stop()` maybe?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

Comment: It loads a document when I click the button, but the img of the button changes after I click it

Comment: Dude I don't know how it does that without looking at the code. I just provided the docs to a method that does what you asked in the title  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What do you mean by "does not prevent the page from reloading." I'm curious why it would be reloading instead of just stopping? You may need to post a small example of code for us to look at. Are you trying to stop a redirect from happening after it's already begun? That may not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was redirecting to:

```
http_response_code(204);
```

So the page stayed as it was before making the new request and but I was still able to use it normally. Thanks to those who answered anyways, the abortable fetch was also an solution.

Answer (score 0):

We really need to see the code you are using to initiate the "document request from the server".

Here is a cool way to cancel if you are doing this type of request.

What about using [abortable-fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch).

Nice [demo here](https://fetch-abort-demo.glitch.me/).